# I am trying to install varnish

Tags: linux, varnish, varnish-4

The instructions in the varnish site are

[varnish install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsiQf.jpg)

isn't rpm --nosignature -i https://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-4.1.el6.rpm
and yum install varnish doing the same thing?
I finally installed varnish but I don't have a clear idea of what I did.Also the file varnish.params is missing (/etc/varnish/varnish.params).Why is that?I can see version with varnish -V command (varnishd (varnish-4.1.4 revision 4529ff7)

Answer (score 0):

I found that "yum install https://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-4.1.el6.rpm" worked fine for me, rpm -i does install an RPM but yum will often complain that it's been installed outside yum which the above resolves.

Re the varnish.params file check /etc/sysconfig/varnish